Connect to socket throwing INVALID ARGUMENTS 22 (MAC)
Issue
The following connect call will throw a Connection Refused (61) on first attempt, and then Invalid Arguments (22) on following attempts, even if the server is ready and listening. This behavior only happens on MacOS. On Linux, the code will throw Connection Refused (111) until the server is up and then it successfully connects.
struct hostent* hp = gethostbyname(node->host.c_str());
if (hp == NULL) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "Failed to acquire ip address for hostname `" << node->host << "`";
    die(os.str());
}

sockaddr_in server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(node->port);
memcpy(&server_address.sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

while (true) {
    std::ostringstream msg;
    msg << "Connecting to server " << node->id << ":" << node->host << ":" << node->port;
    info(msg.str());

    int connect_result = connect(
        client_socket,
        (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
        sizeof(server_address)
    );
    if (connect_result == 0) break;

    if (errno != 111 && errno != 61 && errno != 22) {
        die_with_errno("Unexpected error when connecting to server");
    } else {
        warn_with_errno("Failed to connect");
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}

What I've Tried
I have noticed that if I acquire a new socket fd after each Connection Refused (61) error, the connection will eventually work once the server is ready:
if (errno == 61) {
    client_socket = get_socket();
} else if (errno != 111) {
    die_with_errno("Unexpected error when connecting to server");
}

My guess is that the Connection Refused (61) error is somehow invalidating the socket fd on MacOS.  Is my hacky fix ok above? Is this the intended way to recover? Does it require any extra cleanup on my end? It feels wrong to have to get a new socket fd for every connect attempt.

I think POSIX doesn't specify what happens if you try to reuse a socket after an error like this, so it's implementation-dependent.

You generally can't reuse a socket if connect() fails, you must close() the failed socket and create a new socket before calling connect() again.
